# Is there any relationship between the operator $\partial_z.\, (z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C})$ and $\partial_x,\, \partial_y$?

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory

I don't know if the following question makes any sense but, is there any relationship between the operator $\partial_z, \, (z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C})$ and $\partial_x,\, \partial_y$?
For example, we know that $\partial_z z^2=2z$. It is possible to write $\partial_z (z^2)=2z=\partial_x(z^2)+\partial_y(z^2)+\cdots$ (finite) etc?

The motivation for my question stems from the study of operators of the form $e^{\partial_z}$ and at some point, the reference works with the partial derivatives of $x$ and $y$ respectively ($z=x+iy$)

Comment: $\partial_z = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_x-i\partial_y\right)$ and $\partial_\bar{z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_x+i\partial_y\right)$

Comment: Thanks, but, the question I'm asking is in a general context.

Comment: what does that even mean?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. What you put is valid for all functions? why is that done? In which book could I see that relationship?

Comment: Some textbooks will define the operators without the factor of $1/2$ because we only care about their kernels (for example one way to define holomorphic functions is the subset of analytic functions in ker$(\partial_\bar{z})$). However such derivatives would be computationally bizarre and satisfy equations such as $\partial_z z^2 = 4z$.

Comment: Thanks. I had never seen that definition. In Conway, complex functions, from what I see that definition does not appear. I'll find another book.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138338/discussion-between-eraldcoil-and-ninad-munshi).

Comment: You can calculate these derivatives on your own using your known relationships between $x,y,z,\bar{z}$ and chain rule.

Comment: Thanks. In this note https://joelshapiro.org/Pubvit/Downloads/DbarNotes/dbar.pdf I could see the reason. The $\partial_z$ operator is known as the Cauchy-Riemann operator. Anyway, I'll look for a book where this appeared. Thanks.

Comment: It's also called the complex derivative or holomorphic derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial_z$ is the Cauchy-Riemann operator. Thanks to Ninad.